# How to add the active object name to a StringProperty on the addon when clicking an object?

Tags: python

In operator class I define:

```
active_obj : bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

In panel class I define as below:

```
 obj = context.object
 col.operator("object.enable", text="",
                        icon=icn, emboss=False).active_obj=obj.name
```

But when clicking an object in the scene, it shows nothing without the active object name.

Answer (score 3):

I have given you 2 ways of doing this. One with string property as you required and the second is the one I like in this situation.

````
import bpy

class PROPERTIRES(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    active_obj : bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Active Object is', default = bpy.context.object.name)

class NEWPANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "New Panel"
    bl_idname = "NEW_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "New Panel"
    
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
#       First Way, Your way
        row.prop(bpy.context.scene.my_props, 'active_obj')
#       Second way, I liked with this situation
        layout.label(text= 'Active Object is ' + bpy.context.object.name)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NEWPANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PROPERTIRES)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = PROPERTIRES)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NEWPANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PROPERTIRES)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_props
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: For the 1st way, it pops up an error _RestrictContext object has no attribute object

Comment: You must have at least one object in the scene to run the script.

Comment: Got you, thanks!